# I want to create an 'empty' grid with desired sizes (1 for 'empty', 1 for square grids, 1 for rectangles)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, computer-science

I have done the following code. But, it won't run. What could I have done wrong?
[image]

```
def makeGrid(nRows,nCols):
   grid = []
   for i in range(nRows):
     grid.append([])
     for j in range(nCols):
        grid[i].append('empty')

return grid
```

Comment: What do you mean with _it won't run_. I see there no problem. Your code works. (except that the indent in the question is a little bit broken, but this seems to be a copy&paste issue. In your IDE it seems to be correct). Do you get an error?

Comment: to run your function `makeGrid` you would need to call it. something like this `my_grid=makeGrid(2,3)
print(my_grid)`

Comment: Please fix your Indentation and try to call the program - print(makeGrid(3, 3)) # in a new line, see what happens